# Flutter firestore get stream of document ids from a collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the below Future that returns a String List, instead I would like to return Stream String List with the same document ids list, how do I do that?

```
Future<List<String>> getFollowingUidList(String uid) async{

final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('following').doc(uid).collection('user_following').get();
final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.docs;

List<String> followingList = [];

documents.forEach((snapshot) {
  followingList.add(snapshot.id);
});

return followingList;

}
```

Comment: instead of `[...].get()` which returns a `Future` use `[...].`[snapshots()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) which returns a `Stream`

Comment: @pskink How do I stream the document ids from Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('following').doc(uid).collection('user_following').snapshots();

Comment: you need to "modify" your original `Stream`, more here: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#modify-stream-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the FlutterFire [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes), the `snapshots()` [method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) of a [CollectionReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference-class.html) will return a Stream. In Dart, Streams provide a `map()` [method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/map.html) which allows you to easily transform the Stream and return a new one:

> Transforms each element of this stream into a new stream event.
> Creates a new stream that converts each element of this stream to a new value using the convert function, and emits the result.

Based on this, it would be possible to return a new Stream with document IDs from the `snapshots()` Stream that comes from the CollectionReference. The CollectionReference Stream is of type `QuerySnapshot`, which, according to the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html), contains a `docs` property of [type](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html) `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>`. To finish, this type can provide you with `data` from the `DocumentSnapshots`, [including](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) the ID of the document.

```
Stream<List<String>> returnIDs() {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('testUsers')
        .snapshots()
        .map((querySnap) => querySnap.docs //Mapping Stream of CollectionReference to List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>
        .map((doc) => doc.data.id) //Getting each document ID from the data property of QueryDocumentSnapshot
        .toList());
 }
```

I based this snippet on this [example](https://babinsamrat123.medium.com/fetch-cloud-firestore-data-stream-in-your-flutter-app-using-streamprovider-add-data-to-cloud-fa9971a5985c), which is full of useful scripts to use Streams with Firestore.